# Register greater than immediate instruction in MIPS

Tags: assembly, compare, mips

In MIPS assembly, there are instruction `SLT`, `SLTI`, `SLTU`, `SLTIU` implemented as real hardware instructions. Also, there are instruction for conditional jump when comparing register with zero (greater, greater or equal, less and less or equal), `BE` and `BNE` with registers (except with use `$zero` register) don't matter in this case.

Maybe my question will be stupid, but I can't get with only combinations of this instructions pseudo-instruction that will be looking: `BG Rz, Const, Label`, meaning in C: `if(Rz > direct_value) PC = Label;`.

If we will try to reach it, `SLTI` (= Set If Less Than Immediate) can give us, with use `BE` with `$zero`, only two possible branching and that is register is **less than immediate** or register is **greater or equal immediate**, but not **greater than immediate** without using additional instructions.

Am I missing something? If not, how is this effectively solved?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why not reverse the operands? If immediate cannot be the first, load it to a reg.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned "I can't get with only combinations of this instructions pseudo-instruction that will be looking: BG Rz, Const, Label". So, there is no way to reach it with mentioned instructions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can you use an instruction that doesn't exist? Does [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/pseudojump.html) help?

Comment: @WeatherVane In short only with using two following instructions (not pseudo-instructions) perform pseudo-instruction `BG Rz, Const, Label`. Exactly like `BGE`, `BGT`, `BLE`, `BLT` are demonstrated on [this page](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/pseudojump.html). However, on this page are only used both operands as registers. I need branch if register is greater than immediate.

Comment: That is the same page I linked. It says if there was no speed improvment over using two instructions, it was not included.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okey, you probably didn't understand me. How is pseudo-instruction `BG Register, Immediate, Label` translated into real instructions?

Comment: *"how is this effectively solved?"* by using two instructions.

Comment: @WeatherVane So, how is it translated into direct MIPS32 instructions? If you answer this, it will be enough for me.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, I need compare register with immediate (for example 5), not zero. If your answer is part of any think, just expand your answer. I need complete solution, complete instruction following to branch if register is greater than immediate. I know how to reach it, but I don't know if it is the best solution.

Comment: Subtract the immediate value, then branch test: two instructions. Or: branch <= and then unconditional jump.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's right, thank you.

Comment: Look at the arm documentation for example or any traditional processor that uses the common flags NCVZ, the types of conditionals we do can be reflected with combinations of those flag, and you will find if for example you reverse the operands on a subtract (a compare) then a fair number of your instructions could have gone away why do greater than or equal and less than, when all you need is less than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found exactly what I was looking for. Here is a screenshot that demonstrates everything.

[image: BGTI pseudo-instruction translate]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  It's unusable for blind readers using a screen-reader, and not searchable.  (Not copy-pastable either, which is more of a problem for longer snippets).